# Bucket-fill whole selection rectangle in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

Consider sample Bézier curve with a red stroke:

[image]

Now, I want to paint the background of the whole selection area.
Like this:

[image]

Is there a straight-forward way of achieving this?

This is what I get using standard fill option:

[image]

---

I've created the mockup by creating a rectangle with the same dimensions as the curve, then aligning and grouping the two.
Perhaps it's the only way.

However, I don't quite like edges not aligning perfectly in case of a thicker stroke:

[image]

Furthermore, I thought that the approach with rectangle is workaround-ish and does not produce accurate and scalable result. It does.
Explained in my comment to @user287001 's answer.

Comment: are you sure you're applying the fill to the rectangle and not to the bezier curve?

Comment: I don't understand you. The process of obtaining each of the images has been described in a sufficiently precise manner.

Comment: User @Luciano had a solid idea. In vector graphics programs the fill, when applied to an open curve, behaves exactly as you got, but not wanted. The fill is applied like there was a straight line segment from the beginning to the end. The fill does not fit the bounding box of the object until the object happens to be a horizontal rectangle OR somebody programs a new type of fill that colors the bounding box.

Answer (score 1):

No use to think other ways, if your mockup gives the wanted visual result and the problem is nothing more than visual. Make a group to keep the rectangle and the curve together when moving, rotating or scaling. Recoloring needs a separation.

ADDENDUM due the comment and edit in the question:

To fit the ends of the curve perfectly draw a little longer curve. Make a clipping mask.

Alternatively convert your curve to a filled area and edit its control points. See an example:

[image]

NOTE: the size and the position of the added rectangle are NOT approximate, if you

- at first copy your curve to the clipboard
- select the rectangle and paste the **size** onto it from the clipboard
- select both and align them with the Object > Align & Distribute -tool.

Comment: I've demonstrated understanding of the need for grouping in the original question :)
See the last edit for a little problem with additional rectangle approach.

Comment: @vucalur see the edit

Comment: Guess, I'll have to accept your answer, if nothing better comes by.

Comment: I thought that filling the selection rectangle is doable in, like, 2 clicks; the approach with additional rectangle is incredibly workaround-ish; and, what is more important, does not produce accurate result: I thought, that rounding error would happen: If you specified same dimensions, made the group, resized it to huge dimensions, they would be off by a couple of pixels. But, due to grouping magic, they stay perfectly same size. But if you then ungroup, the two shapes are off. They don't return to perfect alignment then grouped once more.

Comment: @vucalur Added how to fit the curve and the rectangle exactly without clipping and how to make the rectangle excactly to the right size and position.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a rectangle with a border in the same color as the filling color and choose, as contur width, the same width as the Beziers contour width.

If you later change the width of the Bezier curves contour, you just have to change the rectangles contour to the same value.